# Battery alarms and notifications don't work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, power-management, notifications, alarm

It's about some months that I have a strange problem with my laptop battery. In the past, whenever my laptop went about 10% of battery, my operating system Windows 8 showed a notification alarm to inform me about powering off. But it's some months that this just happens a few times and most of the time, my laptop powers off during my works without any alarm about running out of battery.
What do I have to do ? What does this problem for ?

Comment: Maybe your battery is getting old

Comment: How can I determine it ?